# Non-trivial summand in End(\rho)

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Given a finite group representation $\rho:G\to GL_n(\mathbb C)$ one knows that the trivial representation $\mathbb 1$ is contained in $End(\rho)$.

Let $\rho'$ be the other summand, i.e., $\rho'$ is defined by $\rho'\oplus \mathbb 1=End(\rho)$. Some sources say that $\rho'$ is obtained by composing the projection on $PGL_n$ with the adjoint of $PGL_n$.

This may be obvious, but is there an easy way to see that?

Comment: Schur's lemma says $End(\rho) = \mathbb C$, for irreducible $\rho$.  Are you thinking of $\rho \otimes \check \rho = 1 \oplus Ad(\rho)$?

Comment: Your question is not clear at all! What do you mean by "the projection on ${\rm PGL}_n$"? "the adjoint of ${\rm PGL}_n$"?